# Can't get Result from POST request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sending the POST req to my node.js server using jQuery like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.post('/client-request', 
    {
        'contact': $('#contact').val(),
        'budget': $('#budget').text(),
        'message': $('#message').val()
    }, 
    function(data, status){
        console.log(status);
        if (status == 'success') {
            console.log('OKEY');
        } else {
            console.log('NOT OKEY');
        }
    });
});
```

The server gets req properly. I'm not sending any data back from server, just waiting 200OK status and its don't give me a success. Any help please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you add an error handler? And is #submit a submit button? If yes, you are not cancelling its default action.

Comment: What does the server-side code look like? Without it, how can we possibly know what it does? `I'm not sending any data back from server` is probably the key. You MUST respond to the client.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille you were right! After I sending res to client it starts work like it should.